# HDMI Audio doesn't work on AMD RX580 Mac Pro 5,1

Tags: audio, hdmi, mac-pro, mojave

I have a Mac Pro 5,1 2012 and just installed an AMD RX580 GPU. The sound doesn't go through the HDMI so I have to plug into the headphone outlet on the front of the computer (and can't use the speakers on my monitor).

[This post](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/radeon-rx580-no-audio-display-port.255752/) says HDMI doesn't work on non-native GPUs and suggests reading [this](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/applehda-hdmi-audio-guide.234735/). I have Mojave installed and would like some advice on what's the easiest way to get HDMI setup. Looks like there are several ways. I'd prefer the easiest and least complicated/invasive method. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

HDMI Audio doesn't work in Mojave even with supported Hardware.  My box is a MacPro 5,1 with an Nvidia GTX680.  HDMI audio worked flawlessly under High Sierra. Not at all under Mojave.

I am part of the Beta test group and complained of this loss 6 months PRIOR to the Mojave release.  Still nothing as of today 11/30/18.